# Screenshot iOS, MonoGame

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monogame

I am developing a game for iOS using MonoGame.  The game has already been released for Windows 8 (metro) using MonoGame.  We got MonoTouch, and I have had several issues, but only one major issue remains.  I cannot take a screenshot.  Being able to take a screenshot is an essential component in the game, since we have play area sharing, so other users will be able to see what the saved game looks like.  As I understand it, this is unimplemented in the develop3d branch, but I heard from someone that it was implemented in an older version of the develop branch.  Does anyone know a way to get around this?  It seems like a fairly common thing to need to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented this my self, I was going to create a PR but didn't have time.  The code that I used to create screen shots can be found here: [Texture2D.cs](https://github.com/weaverx9x9/MonoGame/blob/local/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/Texture2D.cs)  I have not merged with remote in a while, so not sure how well this will plug into the current source.  Note that the methods you want to look at are SaveAsJpeg and SaveAsPng, the part that was tricky was getting GetTextureData() right.  It's entirely possible that this issue has already been solved by someone else.  But this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For UIKit screens, you can use:

```
UIScreen.Capture()
```

For OpenGL screens, you can use:

```
iPhoneOSGameView.Capture()
```

Comment: I do not see a Capture() method in the iOSGameView class.

Comment: MonoGame does not use iPhoneOSGameView. It has it's own subclass of UIView.

Comment: When I call UIScreen.Capture() with monogame all image is white : (

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it with native iOS APIs:

```
UIViewController controller = game.Services.GetService(typeof(UIViewController)) as UIViewController;

UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(controller.View.Frame.Size);
using (var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
{
    controller.View.Layer.RenderInContext(context);
    using (var image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext())
    {
        //Save the image to file here   
    }
}
UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
```

Check for errors, that is off the top of my head.

I'm guessing the XNA apis are just not implemented.

Comment: I actually did try something like this, all I got were white screen shots. But it may be that I was not doing it correctly.  I will give your code a try.  Thanks!

Comment: So, I used the code provided above, and I get white screen shots, with the dimensions 768 x 1024.  Which I don't understand because this is running on the retina iPad simulator.  I'm thinking that I am not grabbing the correct drawing surface, or that I don't have proper permission to access the drawing surface, I don't know though, I am totally just guessing.  I will try running it on the actual device, but I am seriously doubting that I will get different results.

Comment: So, I found some code to capture the screen and save to disk with OpenTK/OpenGL.  The problem is, from my understanding, in OpenGL ES 2.0 you cannot grab the contents of the frame buffer, which is why this is unimplemented in MonoGame.  Is this correct.  The code I found is here: http://www.opentk.com/doc/graphics/save-opengl-rendering-to-disk

Comment: Yeah, my code above is not taking retina in consideration. But you are right, it sounds like you potentially can't grab an OpenGL screenshot. I would consider making pre-rendered images for each level on iOS. You might have the same problem on Android if you support that platform, also.

Comment: @weaverx9x9 I need to implement same feature. Did you managed to figure it out? Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but I implemented this on my own.  I was going to create a PR but never got around to it.  Here is the Texture2D file that I used that worked for me: https://github.com/weaverx9x9/MonoGame/blob/local/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/Texture2D.cs